# Jupyter notebooks - "Permission denied" when trying to create new notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I've been using jupyter notebooks for the past couple of months with no issue, but suddenly when launching jupyter notebook through the Command Prompt (I'm a Windows 10 user) and try to create a new python3 notebook through the browser, I suddenly receive the following error:

> Permission Denied Error When Creating New Python Notebook

[image]

Anyone know what to do? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling **Anaconda3**. I saw another post which suggested using export `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=""` but `export` wasn't recognized as an internal or external command by the Command Prompt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you made sure that the Python process has admin privileges?

Comment: The `export` command is common to Unix (Linux and MacOS X) command shells.  Perhaps this old thread on the Continuum mailing list will help: [Running IPython under Windows7](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/IcRYtTJtFfw)

Comment: @iamseiko Probably not... how do I check that? I've run the Command Prompt as Administrator but no change to the result unfortunately

Comment: @JimDennis Thanks for the link, though had a look through it and it doesn't seem to be related to jupyter notebooks?

Comment: I've created a new folder and moved all my previous .py files to this new folder, and it seems to have worked. Any idea why the file permissions might have changed for the original file?