# Permission denied to create a new notebook in Jupyter (Pyhtong3) on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, permission-denied

**Goal :** I'm trying to use Jupiter for python3 projects by creating a new notebook.

**Config** : Windows 10, Python 3.6, 64bits, Anaconda

**Error :** Permission denied

```
[I 15:21:39.329 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[W 15:21:39.379 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (127.0.0.1): Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 15:21:39.379 NotebookApp] Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 15:21:39.381 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (127.0.0.1) 52.52ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

**Searched solutions :**

- The question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643648/jupyter-notebooks-permission-denied-when-trying-to-create-new-notebook), but not answered.
- I tried the solution proposed for linux [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272880/cannot-open-new-jupyter-notebook-permission-denied), but it doesn't help. I tried to change folder(.local) permissions with this command : `takeown /f ~/.local/share/jupyter /r` and tried to run with `py -m notebook --allow-root` (all in the cmd terminal).

**Tried out:**

- Reinstal ipykernel, pymzq (allowed me to actually launch jupyter)
- Upgrade ipython, prompt-toolkit, jupyter
- Open Anaconda prompt
- Go to C:\Users\your_name
- Write `jupyter trust untitled.ipynb` (trust is then not a know command)
- Then, write `jupyter notebook`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me is run jupyter command "as Administrator".
Find "Command Prompt" (cmd.exe), perform right click on icon and select "Run as Administrator", after that in opened window run "jupyter notebook" or "jupyter lab" and create new notebook.